# XmlReader - read child

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a trouble with reading string (xml structure) using xmlReader.

```
string xml = @"
<Data>
  <Prices Id="16" Code="C3" >
     <Units>
       <Unit Id="17"/>
      </Units> 
  </Prices>
  <Units>
    <Unit Id="1" IsActive="true" />
    <Unit Id="2" IsActive="true" />
  </Units>
 <Product Id="16" Code="C3" >
      <Names>
       <Name NameVersion="1" Name="C3 " />
      </Names>
      <Units>
       <Unit Id="16"/>
      </Units>
 </Product>
</Data>
"
```

How could I read only Element "Units" with child's id 1 and 2 ?

Actually I tried parsing this string into XDocument.

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xmlFile);
var units = root.Elements("Units").FirstOrDefault();
```

and it works fine but I could work with really big xml and I don't want to parse all string into XDocument. I'm looking for method when I could load partly elements from a string. Also I tried do this using XmlTextReader but this not working in my case

```
using (XmlReader xmlTextReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlFile)))
        {
            if (xmlTextReader.ReadToFollowing(elementName))
            {
                bool isOnNode = xmlTextReader.ReadToDescendant(elementName);
                while (isOnNode)
                {
                    yield return XNode.ReadFrom(xmlTextReader) as XElement;
                    if (!xmlTextReader.IsStartElement(elementName))
                        isOnNode = xmlTextReader.ReadToNextSibling(elementName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Expected output: xElement =

```
<Units>
    <Unit Id="1" IsActive="true" />
    <Unit Id="2" IsActive="true" />
  </Units>
```

Comment: If this is a C# question, then please show your code and explain what exactly your "trouble" is.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you expect the output to be? And what is the reason for using such a low level API for such a small XML document? LINQ to XML would make this trivial.

Comment: I updated the post. I want read only "Units" element which is direct child of Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below an example on how you can parse your xml using `XmlReader`. It iterates over all the nodes until it finds an `Unit` element. It then checks for the presence of the attribute value `Id` and parses the value of `IsActive`:

```
   public static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<Data><Units><Unit Id=\"1\" IsActive=\"true\" /><Unit Id=\"2\" IsActive=\"true\" /></Units><Product Id=\"16\" Code=\"C3\" ><Names><Name NameVersion=\"1\" Name=\"C3 \" /></Names><Units><Unit Id=\"16\"/></Units></Product></Data>";
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(memoryStream);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //keep reading until we see a book element 
            if (reader.Name.Equals("Unit") &&
                (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
            {

                if (reader.GetAttribute("Id") == "1" || reader.GetAttribute("Id") == "2")
                {
                    string isActive = reader.GetAttribute("IsActive");
                }
                else
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

XPathReader can help you. here you can find full article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950778.aspx
short example:
    using System; 
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using GotDotNet.XPath;

```
public class Test{
static void Main(string[] args) {

      try{ 
XPathReader xpr  = new XPathReader("books.xml", "//book/title"); 

            while (xpr.ReadUntilMatch()) {
               Console.WriteLine(xpr.ReadString()); 
             }      
            Console.ReadLine(); 
   }catch(XPathReaderException xpre){
      Console.WriteLine("XPath Error: " + xpre);
      }catch(XmlException xe){
         Console.WriteLine("XML Parsing Error: " + xe);
      }catch(IOException ioe){
         Console.WriteLine("File I/O Error: " + ioe);
      }
   }  
}
```